# Which references should I use for the following topics in Waves and Optics?

Tags: optics, waves, resource-recommendations

**This is the course content for a waves and optics course that I am currently taking:**

Oscillations: Review of simple harmonic motion and damped oscillations, coupled oscillators and normal modes.(4)

Waves: wave equation, superposition of waves with same and different frequency, Lissajous figures, standing waves, dispersion relations and group velocity.(4)

Maxwell's equations: Wave equation, plane, spherical, cylindrical and beam like solutions of the wave equation.(3)

Boundary conditions: reflection and transmission at the boundary.(2) Propagation of light in anisotropic media.(2) Coherence: Spatial and temporal.(2)

Polarization and double refraction, quarter and half wave plates.(2)

Geometrical optics: Paraxial approximation, lens aberrations, ray matrix approach to Gaussian optics, optical systems and resolving power.(8)

Interference: Division of wavefront (Young's double slit) and amplitudes (Newton's rings, Michelson interferometer), multi-wave interference-Fabry-Perot interferometer, thin optical coatings (single and multilayer), interference filters.(6)

Diffraction: Huygen-Fresnel and Kirchhoff's theories.(2)

Fresnel diffraction: rectangular, circular and zone plates.(2)

Fraunhoffer diffraction: Slits (single, double) and grating and circular aperture.(2)

Introduction to metamaterials.(1)

Due to Covid-19, this semester was botched up and the instructor managed to teach only a fraction of the course. I am currently using Vibrations and Waves by AP French and Griffiths for the waves section.

I am looking for textbook recommendations for the other topics in the above list. If possible, please mention the topic which is present in each book.

Comment: You should check out 

https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Book recommendations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/)